# How to map two different responses from an REST API to two different POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a use case where a service returns two different responses for the same `REST API` call. Only the response value is different, but the key is the same. Please refer to the sample responses below,

## Response 1

```
{
   "Polygon": {
   "type": "polygon",
   "coordinates": [
         [
           [
             [
               -128.419935,
               31.761895
             ],
             [
               88.53,
               87.24
                ]
              ]
            ]
         ]
     }
}
```

## Response 2

```
{
   "Polygon": {
   "type": "MultiPolygon",
   "coordinates": [
         [
           [
             [
               -118.419935,
               33.761895
             ],
             [
               89.53,
               86.24
                ]
              ]
            ]
         ]
     }
}
```

If we read the response carefully, then we can understand that the two responses but differ only by value (i.e. coordinates). The coordinates are the two different nested levels of `List`. So I'm not sure how should I map the response. I'm using `Jackson` for mapping the response.

I did have a look at this [SO](http://Mapping%20two%20different%20JSON's%20field%20names%20to%20one%20POJO%20property) question, but that addresses if the property values are different. Can someone through some lights on it.

Comment: This is not valid json.

Comment: Have you tried abstraction? The REST API can return an object like "Polygon", which is an abstract superclass. And then there are the two children "MultiPolygon" and "SinglePolygon", implementing the specific behaviour.

Comment: Change the return type of the method to `Object` and then return either the first or the second. TBH I am a bit unsure what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Lino. Your suggestion helped me to figure out a solution to my problem. I'm from the `C++` background but working with `JAVA` now. I realised the `Object` is the root of the `class` hierarchy i.e. its `superclass` for all the class. So my solution to the above problem would like as below,

```
public class Polygon {

    private data boundingPolygon;

    public static class data {
        private String type;
        private Object coordinates;
    }
}
```

I have tested this and it works for me.